# How to add the data to spreadsheet by using java?

Tags: java, google-sheets

How to insert the data in spreadsheet by using java

```
ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("EmpNo", "1234");  
row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("empno", "12345");
row = spreadsheetService.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
```

Expected output:

```
EmpNo empno
1234  12345
```

CurrnetOutput:

```
EmpNo empno
12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [how to write the data in spreadsheet(reapated headers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159362/how-to-write-the-data-in-spreadsheetreapated-headers)

Have been looking through the documentation ([old doc](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/CustomElementCollection#setValueLocal%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [new doc](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=de-DE)) and as far as I can tell, it has not been documented whether `setValueLocal(String header, String value)` accepts a case-sensitive header value or not.

So, based on what you show, it appears that the specified header is not case-sensitive, meaning that the easiest way to fix this, is by renaming the headers in the spreadsheet giving them unique names.

Comment: hey thanks for the replay but in my project i have no choice to take unique names for header because the end user enter the values so is there any another choice to set the values

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no other options - but I am by no means a Google spreadsheet API expert - so there might be someone else out there who can answer this question better / more precisely than me :)

Comment: LOL at the circular links "possible duplicate of"